# Looking for \nmid but with a larger, more pronounced slash

Tags: symbols, unicode-math

Like the title says, I'm looking for a version of `\nmid` that gives a longer, more pronounced slash. The reason is that I'm projecting the results onto a screen using OneNote, which makes the resulting .pdf a little blurry, and the small slash in the standard `\nmid` is hard for my students to read.

I've been searching for solutions, and some things I've tried:

`\not\mid`: Gives the same results as `\nmid`

`\centernot\mid` (using `centernot` package): Perfect, except that I'm also wanting to use `unicode-math` to load the Libertinus Math font, and this throws off `\centernot` in a weird looking way.

`\notdivides` from the `mathabx` package: Good, but adding the package to my preamble throws a lot of "already defined" errors, which I assume means that it's conflicting with other packages I am loading. I suppose I could `\let\relax` these, but I'd like a cleaner, more modern solution if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic ingredients:

1. in `mathabx.dcl` we find `\DeclareMathSymbol{\notdivides}{3}{matha}{"1F}`
2. in `mathabx.sty` we find

   ```
   \DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
   \DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
        <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
        <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
        }{}
   \DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
   \DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{matha}{m}{n}
   ```

Nowadays the font shape declaration can be much better, but the changes are easy.

However, you also need to import `\divides`, as the following example shows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%%% import \notdivides
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> matha5
  <5.5-6.5> matha6
  <6.5-7.5> matha7
  <7.5-8.5> matha8
  <8.5-9.5> matha9
  <9.5-11> matha10
  <11-> matha12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{matha}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\divides}{3}{matha}{"17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\notdivides}{3}{matha}{"1F}

\begin{document}

$a\mid b \nmid c$ (CM and amssymb)

$a\mid b \notdivides c$ (CM and mathabx)

$a\divides b \notdivides c$ (both mathabx)

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure it really solves your problem with a blurry projector.

Comment: This works a treat, and I would never have figured it out on my own. Thanks very much!

The blurry projector is my own cross to bear, but this longer slash should at least be a bit more legible.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a new symbol by superimposing a rotated `-` on `\mid`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx, amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Nmid}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\N@mid\relax}}
\newcommand{\N@mid}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \negthickspace\rotatebox{42}{$\m@th#1-$}\negthickspace\cr
    \hfil$\m@th#1\mid$\hfil\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\Nmid b\nmid c$

\end{document}
```